# Generating a Fact Table from a presentation linkbase

Tags: xml, xbrl, edgar

This is a follow up question from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087829/xbrl-dimensions-linkbase-parsing).

Having now created the Model Structure from the presentation linkbase found [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312516439878/0001193125-16-439878-index.htm), I now would like to extract the Fact Table information.

The model structure is:

```
us-gaap_IncomeStatementAbstract

Statement [Table]                                           us-gaap_StatementTable
    Legal Entity [Axis]                                     dei_LegalEntityAxis
        Entity [Domain]                                     dei_EntityDomain
    Statement [Line Items]                                  us-gaap_StatementLineItems
        Net sales                                           us-gaap_SalesRevenueNet
        Cost of sales                                       us-gaap_CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold
        Gross margin                                        us-gaap_GrossProfit
        Operating expenses:                                 us-gaap_OperatingExpensesAbstract
            Research and development                        us-gaap_ResearchAndDevelopmentExpense
            Selling, general and administrative             us-gaap_SellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense
            Total operating expenses                        us-gaap_OperatingExpenses
        Operating income                                    us-gaap_OperatingIncomeLoss
        Other income/(expense), net                         us-gaap_NonoperatingIncomeExpense
        Income before provision for income taxes            us-gaap_IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIn...
        Provision for income taxes                          us-gaap_IncomeTaxExpenseBenefit
        Net income                                          us-gaap_NetIncomeLoss
        Earnings per share:                                 us-gaap_EarningsPerShareAbstract
            Basic                                           us-gaap_EarningsPerShareBasic
            Diluted                                         us-gaap_EarningsPerShareDiluted
        Shares used in computing earnings per share:        us-gaap_WeightedAverageNumberOfSharesOutstandingAb...
            Basic                                           us-gaap_WeightedAverageNumberOfSharesOutstandingBa...
            Diluted                                         us-gaap_WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutsta...
        Cash dividends declared per share                   us-gaap_CommonStockDividendsPerShareDeclared
```

The Fact Table that I am trying to recreate from the xml documents contains this information:

[image]

This fact table can then be rendered to produce this table:

[image]

The problem is that I am not sure how to get the specific facts for each line item. For example, the model structure contains the element `Net sales` which has the concept `us-gaap_SalesRevenueNet`. The [instance document](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312516439878/aapl-20151226.xml) contains the following references to `us-gaap_SalesRevenueNet`:

```
    contextRef  decimals    fact_value  id_x    tag unitRef {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}arcrole   {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href  {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}type  {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil  cik_x   cik_y   id_y    startDate   endDate instant
471 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0  -6  74599000000 id_5473321_00DC1C18-22C7-426B-AF70-F6B281547EC4_2_0 {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0  2014-09-28  2014-12-27  
527 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1138497  -6  30566000000 id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_1002_0  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1138497  2014-09-28  2014-12-27  
529 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1173722  -6  5448000000  id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_2002_6  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1173722  2014-09-28  2014-12-27  
531 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1181338  -6  16144000000 id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_3002_4  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1181338  2014-09-28  2014-12-27  
533 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1184739  -6  17214000000 id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_4002_2  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1184739  2014-09-28  2014-12-27  
535 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1257623  -6  5227000000  id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_5002_8  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1257623  2014-09-28  2014-12-27  
628 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0  -6  75872000000 id_5473321_00DC1C18-22C7-426B-AF70-F6B281547EC4_1_0 {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0  2015-09-27  2015-12-26  
701 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1138497  -6  29325000000 id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_1001_0  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1138497  2015-09-27  2015-12-26  
703 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1173722  -6  4794000000  id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_2001_6  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1173722  2015-09-27  2015-12-26  
705 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1181338  -6  18373000000 id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_3001_4  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1181338  2015-09-27  2015-12-26  
707 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1184739  -6  17932000000 id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_4001_2  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1184739  2015-09-27  2015-12-26  
709 eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1257623  -6  5448000000  id_5473321_493F2921-7163-4A93-9BC8-89E0F5E62B3B_5001_8  {http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31}SalesRevenueNet iso4217_USD                 0000320193  0000320193  eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0_1106947x1257623  2015-09-27  2015-12-26
```

Of the 12 facts shown, only two are required for the fact table - they are the facts with the contextRef of `eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0` and `eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0`.

These contextRef id's correspond to the following facts in the instance document:

```
<context id="eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0">
<entity>
<identifier scheme="http://www.sec.gov/CIK">0000320193</identifier>
</entity>
<period>
<startDate>2014-09-28</startDate>
<endDate>2014-12-27</endDate>
</period>
</context>

<context id="eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20151226_0">
<entity>
<identifier scheme="http://www.sec.gov/CIK">0000320193</identifier>
</entity>
<period>
<startDate>2015-09-27</startDate>
<endDate>2015-12-26</endDate>
</period>
</context>
```

These contextRefs are essentially the `Period Axis` elements. I can't tell how the period axis are being determined from the xml [documents](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312516439878/0001193125-16-439878-index.htm) and, therefore, cannot reproduce the fact table. Can anyone shed any light on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are pasting is a simplified rendering, not a complete rendering of the IncomeStatement.

A complete rendering is:
[image]

You can derive that information from the [definition linkbase](http://xlink:role=%22http://www.apple.com/taxonomy/role/StatementOfIncome%22) where it says:

[image]

For example, one of the SalesRevenueNet that you are listing is linked to context "eol_PE2035----1510-Q0015_STD_91_20141227_0_1106947x1173722". This context contains a restriction on Axis "us-gaap:StatementBusinessSegmentsAxis". Therefore, this context is outside of the StatementOfIncome because this axis is not defined in the hypercube of the according definition linkbase.

I assume you are doing this for learning purposes? Otherwise, I'd suggest you use a service like secxbrl.info:

- [Factable as a list (JSON)](http://secxbrl.28.io/v1/_queries/public/api/facttable-for-component.jq?section=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com%2Ftaxonomy%2Frole%2FStatementOfIncome&format=json&token=c3049752-4d35-43da-82a2-f89f1b06f7a4&aid=0001193125-16-439878&ticker=aapl) (you can also get csv, html, or xml)
- [Factable as a rendered table (JSON)](http://secxbrl.28.io/v1/_queries/public/api/spreadsheet-for-component.jq?section=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com%2Ftaxonomy%2Frole%2FStatementOfIncome&format=json&token=c3049752-4d35-43da-82a2-f89f1b06f7a4&aid=0001193125-16-439878&ticker=aapl) (you can also get html)